# Pyspark: How to get time difference in seconds while split it into each days

Tags: pyspark

question itself might be a little awkward while I will show you what i mean by example.
here is the dataframe that i am dealing with

```
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|       id|         start_time|             ts_utc|stream_duration_total|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|       33|2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|               298994|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I calculated column stream_duration_total(time difference in seconds) by myself, while i actually want to get a multiple rows like,
apparently 298994 is the total time difference in seconds. However, I was asked to get a daily info which means I need to calculate a data frame like down below. The below one splits the seconds into each days.Lets say,2022-07-03 00:07:20 to the end of 2022-07-03, they have a 85959 seconds time gap, and so on.

```
id start_time          ts_utc               dt  stream_duration_total 
33 2022-07-03 00:07:20 2022-07-06 11:10:34  2022-07-03     85959
33 2022-07-03 00:07:20 2022-07-06 11:10:34  2022-07-04     86400
33 2022-07-03 00:07:20 2022-07-06 11:10:34  2022-07-05     86400
33 2022-07-03 00:07:20 2022-07-06 11:10:34  2022-07-06     40235
```

PLEASE help me!!! Thanks in advance!
Linus got it right

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Why the many code tags? What does this have to do with `R`, `sql`, `python` and `pyspark`? It is best to stick to one language. More to the point: How are you calculating `stream_duration_total`? In other words, how do you get from your input data to your output data?

Comment: Which database are you using and do you need solution in SQL ? If not, then remove SQL tag and if yes, remove other tags and add correct RDBMS

Comment: @MauritsEvers - Guess OP needs number of seconds for each day, so for first day, it would be from 4th July midnight - start time, and until last day, total number of seconds in the day.

Comment: @Utsav THANK YOU!!! that is exactly what i ask. and for your questions, i am dealing with pyspark, so all i need its just a returned data frame like my example above. FYI, i will finally store that into a parquet file in aws s3.

Comment: how did you calculate for the first row `85959`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I apologize for any misunderstanding above, and i change my tag to pyspark. it is the one that i am using. FYI, i get "stream_duration_total" by unix_timestamp(col("ts_utc"))-unix_timestamp(col("start_time"))

Comment: @samkart i calculated by google lol. it is just an example, i calculate the time difference between "2022-07-03 00:07:20" and "2022-07-03 23:59:59"

Comment: and how did you get the last one `40235`? were the `start_time` and `dt` subtracted? that would result in 258759 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution of pyspark

```
# start of udf parse_date_range
@udf(returnType=ArrayType(DateType()))
def parse_date_range(start_date, end_date):
    dates = []
    
    for i in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1):
        dates.append( start_date + timedelta(days=i) )
    
    return dates
# end of udf parse_date_range

df = spark.createDataFrame([(33, "2022-07-03 00:07:20","2022-07-06 11:10:34")], ['id', 'start_time', 'ts_utc'])\
        .withColumn("start_time", col("start_time").cast("timestamp"))\
        .withColumn("ts_utc", col("ts_utc").cast("timestamp"))
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- start_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- ts_utc: timestamp (nullable = true)

df = df.withColumn("split_date", parse_date_range(col("start_time"), col("ts_utc")))\
       .withColumn("split_date", explode(col("split_date")))\
    .withColumn("stream_duration_total", when(col("start_time").cast("date") == col("split_date"), 86399 + col("split_date").cast("timestamp").cast("long") - col("start_time").cast("long"))
                                        .when(col("ts_utc").cast("date") == col("split_date"), 1 + col("ts_utc").cast("long") - col("split_date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
                                        .otherwise(lit(86400)))

df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
| id|         start_time|             ts_utc|split_date|stream_duration_total|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 33|2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|2022-07-03|                85959|
| 33|2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|2022-07-04|                86400|
| 33|2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|2022-07-05|                86400|
| 33|2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|2022-07-06|                40235|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!, It throws me an error.
TypeError: 'Column' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I AM not a expert either on python or pyspark, i guess something went wrong on iterators in your udf

Comment: u can add df.printSchema() to make sure that ur columns "start_time" & "ts_utc" type of timestamp.

Comment: i checked that, and it was all timestamp by now. thx again, however i cant even run your code since your code creates a new df with two timestamp type. It throws same error.

Comment: u can post ur code at the end this question.

Comment: posted! same as yours

Comment: i guess in range(), we are supposed to put a interger, and by your code (end_date - start_date).days is a dataframe column,that is why it throws :'Column' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: u missed `@udf(returnType=ArrayType(DateType()))`

Comment: i am appreciate if u accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without the use of UDFs as well. The [`sequence()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html) function will help you create the dates between the two timestamps, and that list can be exploded to create rows.

```
data_ls = [
    ('33', '2022-07-03 00:07:20', '2022-07-06 11:10:34')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'start_ts', 'ts_utc']). \
    withColumn('start_ts', func.col('start_ts').cast('timestamp')). \
    withColumn('ts_utc', func.col('ts_utc').cast('timestamp'))

# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
# |id |start_ts           |ts_utc             |
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
# |33 |2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('dt_seq', func.expr('sequence(to_date(start_ts), to_date(ts_utc), interval 1 day)')). \
    withColumn('dt', func.explode('dt_seq')). \
    withColumn('end_ts', func.from_unixtime(func.date_add('dt', 1).cast('timestamp').cast('int') - 1).cast('timestamp')). \
    withColumn('duration',
               func.when(func.to_date('start_ts') == func.col('dt'), func.col('end_ts').cast('long') - func.col('start_ts').cast('long')).
               when(func.to_date('ts_utc') == func.col('dt'), func.col('end_ts').cast('long') - func.col('ts_utc').cast('long')).
               otherwise(func.col('end_ts').cast('long') - func.lag('end_ts').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt')).cast('long'))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--------+
# |id |start_ts           |ts_utc             |dt_seq                                          |dt        |end_ts             |duration|
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--------+
# |33 |2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|[2022-07-03, 2022-07-04, 2022-07-05, 2022-07-06]|2022-07-03|2022-07-03 23:59:59|85959   |
# |33 |2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|[2022-07-03, 2022-07-04, 2022-07-05, 2022-07-06]|2022-07-04|2022-07-04 23:59:59|86400   |
# |33 |2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|[2022-07-03, 2022-07-04, 2022-07-05, 2022-07-06]|2022-07-05|2022-07-05 23:59:59|86400   |
# |33 |2022-07-03 00:07:20|2022-07-06 11:10:34|[2022-07-03, 2022-07-04, 2022-07-05, 2022-07-06]|2022-07-06|2022-07-06 23:59:59|46165   |
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--------+
```

I've retained all calculated fields for your understanding. You can select only the required ones - `select('id', 'start_ts', 'ts_utc', 'dt', 'duration')`.